# How to make folder always writeable by apache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, ubuntu-server

I want to make a folder always writeable by PHP.

I changed the folder permission temprorarly to 777, but the content of the folder is uploaded by a ftp user, so every time I rerun the script I get this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/var/www/html/.../file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/.../autoimport.php on line 25
```

The same is happening to me in this script, where I show the content of error.log. I change it to 777 but when it is re-generated I lost access again.

```
Warning: fopen(/var/log/apache2/error.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/admin/errorlog.php on line 48
Could not get lines from file - /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: What is the permission of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: -rw-r----- 1 root     adm         75430 Nov 20 12:50 error.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I typically do this in my server setups is to create a group for the website, then use a combination of setgid and umask to make sure that files remain writable by the applications I want. Step by step guide below:

1/ Create a new group for your website:

```
$ sudo groupadd web-grp
```

2/ Add the user the webserver runs as to the group:

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a www-data web-grp
```

3/ chown the diretories and files that you want the server to have access to:

```
$ sudo chown -R :web-grp /path/to/website
```

4/ Set the gid bit and other permissions on those directories:

```
$ sudo chmod -R ug+rw /path/to/website
$ find /path/to/website -type d -exec chmod g+xs {} \;
```

5/ Set your ftp program's umask to `002`. This will depend on your ftp client and server, search around to figure out how to do this for your particular setup.

6/ Restart your web server to pick up the new group permission:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

The interesting thing here is the `setgid` bit on those directories will cause new files created in the directories to have the same group by default. This means you don’t need `777` permissions—which means you have more security as well as a system that should continue to work.

The `umask` part is also important. New files will have the permission bits in the `umask` stripped, so if your `umask` is `022`, the new files will not be group writable, and things won't work very well.

I've been using this setup very successfully for a number of years now.